# create two column responsive css html design that merges into 1 column when shrunk or viewed on mobile device

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design, multiple-columns

So i'm not very web savvy, Im creating a FAQ page on my WordPress site, and I want to make a responsive two column layout with a list of questions that when the user clicks on one of these anchors, it takes them down to that answer on the page, like most FAQs. I want the list of these links to be in a two column layout, while everything else on the site is just 1 column layout, and I want it to be pretty smooth and good looking. I want the two column layout to eventually merge into one column when the screen shrinks/is used by a tablet or iPhone.  Here is my code, I feel like I'm close but it's looking bad when I implement it in WordPress. Any suggestions?

**CSS**

```
.linkcontainer {
  width:100%;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.linkleft {
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
.linkright {
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}

@media(max-width:400px) {
  .linkleft {
    width:100px;
    float:none;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
  }
  .linkright {
    width:100px;
    float:none;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="linkcontainer">
  <div class="linkleft">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#unique-identifier1">Can I ?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#unique-identifier2">How much does ?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#unique-identifier3">Is the process ?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#unique-identifier4">What do I need to ?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#unique-identifier5">What is the date?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#unique-identifier6">What information does the ?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#unique-identifier7">After being ?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#unique-identifier8">Where do I?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#unique-identifier9">How do I ?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#unique-identifier10">How do I ?</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="linkright">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#unique-identifier11">Registering as a </a></li>
      <li><a href="#unique-identifier12">Registering </a></li>
      <li><a href="#unique-identifier13">Am I able to charge ?    </a></li>
      <li><a href="#unique-identifier14">Can others be ?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#unique-identifier15">Can I perform ?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#unique-identifier16">What are the age limits ?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#unique-identifier17">What is the definition of ?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#unique-identifier18">What is the definition ?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#unique-identifier19">All other questions CLICK HERE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#unique-identifier20">All other OTHER questions CLICK HERE</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try setting `width: 100%;` in your media query styles.

Comment: What doesn't work? Here's a demo of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/6njFL/. And it appears to work as expected to me. Although you probably want to set the width to `100%` rather than `100px` in your media query.

Comment: Well when I test it using firefoxs developer responsive design tool, once I shrink the width to under 320 I dont see half of the list? there should be 20 items, and when I get down to that width I only see 10....but your right, it should work!! thats why Im a bit frustrated, could it be something to do with wordpress maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mobile first approach to achieve responsive layout. You should expand the CSS by yourself to fit your WordPress theme.

**CSS**

```
.linkcontainer {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.linkleft, .linkright {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
    .linkleft, .linkright {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cuplizian/ZDA6v/).

Comment: +1. As of TwentyTwelve (I think?!) This is the norm design for the "flagship" themes shipped with WP installs. These themes are great to learn responsive WP design..

Comment: Maybe, I didn't check it when I wrote the answer. Being said, TwentyTwelve (and any official theme afterwards) is a great example to learn responsive design **and** WordPress Theme Development.

Comment: AHH this is what I want!!! but I tried your code and when I preview it in wordpress, it just creates 1 column...it doesn't even display both now. WEIRD. I'll keep messing with it. I tested it locally and it works. so it's definitely something with my wordpress that is conflicting.

Comment: @user3688814 Is it displaying a blank space or nothing? I've edited my answer and my fiddle to see if it works. Looks like I forgot to give `overflow: auto;` to `.linkcontainer`

Comment: No its just now displaying all those li elements in a single column, even when the window is max.

Comment: WOW found out why...found a closing </p> right before .linkleft,.linkright. wowowowowowowowow. guess when I copied your code wordpress somehow added a closing </p>..(facepalm)

Answer (score 0):

Add a CSS mobile media query and set the width of `.linkright` and `.linkleft` to 100%(instead of 100px which is what you have now).

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 400px) {
   .linkleft {
     width:100%;
     float:none;
   }
   .linkright {
     width:100%;
     float:none;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your media queries, try using a percentage width value, such as

```
width:95%;
```

also it may help if you remove the float and add

```
clear:both;
```